# Segmentation fault after program runs correctly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a project for school in C and I'm getting a strange problem.
My program is running normally but I'm getting a Segmentation Fault right at the end, after the last command, and I don't understand why.

Here is my code: (Sorry for the Portuguese prints)

```
void main_args(int argc, char* argv[], struct main_data* data)
{   
    char *str;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {   
        strcat(str, argv[i]);
        strcat(str, " ");
    }
    if(argc != 6 || sscanf(str, "%d %d %d %d %d", &data->max_ops, &data->buffers_size, &data->n_clients, &data->n_proxies, &data->n_servers) != 5)
    {   
        if(argc == 1){
            printf("Uso: sovaccines max_ops buffers_size n_clients n_proxies n_servers\n");
            printf("Exemplo: ./bin/sovaccines 10 10 1 1 1\n");
        }else{
            printf("Parâmetros incorretos! Exemplo de uso: ./bin/sovaccines 10 10 1 1 1\n");
        }
    }

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct main_data* aux = malloc(sizeof(struct main_data));
        
    main_args(argc, argv, aux);
    printf("primeiro: %d\n", aux->max_ops);
    printf("segundo: %d\n", aux->buffers_size);
    printf("terceiro: %d\n", aux->n_clients);
    printf("quarto: %d\n", aux->n_proxies);
    printf("quinto: %d\n", aux->n_servers);
    free(aux);
    printf("What the hell\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the output is:

[image]

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: `strcat(str, argv[i]);` - `str` is just a pointer, there is no memory to copy the string into.

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question, pasting all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Better to not use `str` at all and just `sscanf` or `strtol` the arguments one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a segfault because the `char *str` was never allocated with some memory. You need to initialize it in the right way:

```
// Replace 128 with your preferable number of chars
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
```

**Note:** When you do manually allocate memory like this, it needs to be freed also as soon as its usage is over. This can be done by using `free(ptr)`:

```
// After usage of 'str'
free(str);
```

Lastly, to initialize the newly created string with some character before the usage of `strcat()`:

```
str[0] = '\0'; // Initializing the first character with a null-terminator
```

After this, you will no longer hit with the segfault.

Here's a [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HJjIauyzO).

Comment: Casting the `malloc` return value should not be needed.

Comment: @dxiv Edit complete. Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Within function main_args,
you are declaring str as a pointer, but not allocating memory to it to store.
Use
int ArgsStringSize = 100;
char *str = (char *)malloc(ArgsStringSize);
or
char str[1000];